# Responsive Design Issues with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So here's my problem:
Started working on a website and as the trend goes I went for responsive layout, using bootstrap (12 grid system). So I have to main elements in body which are a heading and an SVG path animation done with LazyLinePainter. So the problem I have is that the heading, is responsive, it stays in the middle no matter the size of the window, yet the animation refuses to do so. I've used same classes on both divs and can't come out with a solution to the problem so that's why I am writing here. I am posting both the html and css:

HTML
http://codepen.io/TresV/pen/bNNZjm.html

CSS
http://codepen.io/TresV/pen/bNNZjm.css

```
    /*=======MAIN CSS=======*/

body { 
    background:#2ecc71;

}

#pencilandbrackets {
    width: 31.5%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -155px;
}

#title {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 4.13em;
    position: fixed;
    top:40%;
    left:50%;
    margin: -1.0em 0px 0px -3.2em;
    color: #2c3e50;
    display: block;
}

.lazy-line svg {
  width:300% !important;
}
```

Here's a life version:
http://thecodehome.tk/new.html

NOTE: Hosting is unreliable so it may not be up at all times.

Thanks in advance for you time and effort!

Comment: Can you put this into a JSFiddle for experimentation?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work well, but here it is :
http://jsfiddle.net/3jL5uw4y/1/

Comment: What browser are you using? Looks fine to me in the latest version of Chrome...

Comment: ...Or are you referring to the height of the browser?

Comment: I am using the latest version too, try inspecting, then click the little phone icon in the developer tools window, its in the upper left corner, then set up Device for Nexus 5 for example. Also when you open the life version, try resizing the window only horizontally.